# WCF service, Application Domain and web sites

Tags: wcf, iis, appdomain, svc

I have many [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) services (SVC files), and I want to host them in IIS.
I was wondering:

- Is it better to create each one on its own web site?
- Or have them all together live on the same web site?

What is the difference?

I read that each service will have its own [Application Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain)?
Is there any articles that describe the relation between a WCF service and an Application Domain?

Answer (score 3):

An [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain) is used to isolate applications so that they do not affect each other. Having a separate website for each service therefore offers higher [fault-tolerance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerance), and enables you to update only the changing service without affecting the others. However deployment will require a little more work. Also probably more resources will be consumed and initialization will take a little longer (since more application domains will be created), but if it's not a time or performance-critical application those may not be of much concern to you.

I think if there's a good separation between your services, your services have a (subjectively) reasonable complexity and the resulting overhead is negligible for you, it would be better to go for separate websites, otherwise not. (Yeah, in summary, it depends.)

Note: You might also want to take a look at this article:
[Hosting multiple WCF services as one single service](http://www.meineck.net/2008/04/wcf-hosting-multiple-wcf-services-as.html)